# changing java heap size globally on Ubuntu?

Tags: java, ubuntu, jvm

Oracle java process on my Linux Ubuntu only sets min. heap size

jps -lvm
2639 sun.tools.jps.Jps -lvm -Dapplication.home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle -Xms8m

I am trying to set maximum heap size by setting JAVA_OPTS in /etc/environment, of /home/me/.profile

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Xms128m -Xmx1024m"
```

but it doesn't seem to work: after the reboot i still have the same opts

jps -lvm
sun.tools.jps.Jps -lvm -Dapplication.home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle -Xms8m

Answer (score 1):

You could use java -Xmx4096m in order to set your heap to 4 GB.

you could then add export _JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xmx4096m to your shell by their (.bashrc, .zshrc) file.

Answer (score 1):

It's the `jps` executable (a native program) that sets it to `8M` for running `sun.tools.jps.Jps`. Presumably it doesn't need more than that.

Run a different program with the `java` command and see what parameters it gets by default.

Answer (score -1):

1. It's

   export JAVA_OPTIONS=...
   Not JAVA_OPTS, or _JAVA_OPTIONS
   2.
   jps -lvm 2639 sun.tools.jps.Jps -lvm -Dapplication.home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle -Xms8m
   prints jvm settings for jps itself

Comment: Answering your own questions is alright, but what kind of answer is this supposed to be?